# Manual latex section IEEE standard

Tags: latex, pdflatex, sections

I defined two new sections under /paragraph section. One is '\mysection' while another is '\myszsection'. \mysection is not resetting and after using mysection paragraph number is not increasing.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{chngcntr}


\newcounter{mysection}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\titleclass{\mysection}{straight}[\part]
\titleformat{\mysection}[hang]
  {\itshape \normalsize}{\themysection}{0em}{.}
\titlespacing{\mysection}{25pt}{0ex }{0 ex }
\renewcommand{\themysection}{\roman{mysection}}
\renewcommand{\theparagraph}{\themysection.\arabic{paragraph}}
\counterwithin{paragraph}{mysection}


\newcounter{myzsection}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{6}
\titleclass{\myzsection}{straight}[\part]
\titleformat{\myzsection}[hang]
  {\itshape \normalsize}{\themyzsection}{1em}{}
\titlespacing{\myzsection}{33pt}{0ex }{0 ex }
\renewcommand{\themyzsection}{\arabic{myzsection}}
\renewcommand{\theparagraph}{\themyzsection.\arabic{paragraph}}
\counterwithin{paragraph}{myzsection}
\contentsmargin{1em}




\begin{document}


\section{Introduction}
gg
\subsection{deatails}\label{AA}
gg
\subsubsection{gg again}
gg
\paragraph{gg this too}
gg
\mysection{problem}
gg
\myzsection{problem}
gg
\paragraph{problem1}
When i added them, paragraph number stopped increasing. What to do?
\mysection{problem2}


The counter is not resetting for the new defined sections. When i use them under another section it continues increasing from before. What to do?



\end{document}
```

1. When i added them, paragraph number stopped increasing. What to do?
2. The counter is not resetting for the new defined sections. When i use them under another section it continues increasing from before. What to do?

Comment: please don't post code fragments, make a [mre]

Comment: Check this out now. I have edited and added reproducable code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your code, you are resetting your `paragraph` counter at `my(z)section`, but you need the other way round (and you must also not include the `my(z)section` counter within the paragraph number):

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{chngcntr}


\newcounter{mysection}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\titleclass{\mysection}{straight}[\part]
\titleformat{\mysection}[hang]
  {\itshape \normalsize}{\themysection}{0em}{.}
\titlespacing{\mysection}{25pt}{0ex }{0 ex }
\counterwithin{mysection}{paragraph}

%
\newcounter{myzsection}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{6}
\titleclass{\myzsection}{straight}[\part]
\titleformat{\myzsection}[hang]
  {\itshape \normalsize}{\themyzsection}{1em}{}
\titlespacing{\myzsection}{33pt}{0ex }{0 ex }
\counterwithin{myzsection}{paragraph}
\contentsmargin{1em}


\renewcommand{\themysection}{\roman{mysection}}
\renewcommand{\themyzsection}{\arabic{myzsection}}

\begin{document}


\section{Introduction}
gg
\subsection{deatails}\label{AA}
gg
\subsubsection{gg again}
gg
\paragraph{gg this too}
gg
\mysection{problem}
gg
\myzsection{problem}
gg
\paragraph{problem1}
When i added them, paragraph number stopped increasing. What to do?
\mysection{problem2}


The counter is not resetting for the new defined sections. When i use them under another section it continues increasing from before. What to do?



\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me. I was somehow missing that thing.